# Problems animating UICollectionView bounds with a nonzero contentOffset

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

Sigh. Second question in two days. I'm starting to not like UICollectionView quite so much.

Ok. I have a UICollectionView set up, working nicely, and a custom layout object managing the... er... layout. I'd post code but there's tons of it and I'm not certain which parts would be relevant. Mostly I just followed this tutorial: http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial

Now herein lies the problem. If I scroll my collection view away from contentOffset 0,0, then cause its bounds to animate, the start location of any cells that were already visible and are remaining visible is a long way out! They arrive at the right place, but start about 60 pixels too far left and too far down. Always the same amount each time no matter how far I've scrolled from 0,0. The weird thing is, so long as I don't move away from 0,0 it all animates exactly as I want it to, no problems whatsoever. Somehow the contentOffset appears to be interfering with the current frame of my content cells, and in a completely nonsensical way.

It's really bizarre and I can't work out why it's happening. Anyone got a clue?

[EDIT] a little more information. As an experiment, I changed the layout style of my collection view so that it only changed width rather than height when it resized. Now it appears that the starting Y positions are correct, so it could well be an unusual bug involving autoresizing. For the record, I have checked my various cells and they are all set to top/left, fixed width and height, so that's not the problem.

[EDIT] And more information. It seems that, when the bounds changes, the layout view is asked if it should invalidate. Returning YES is the only way to animate the bounds change. However, what THEN happens is that the collectionView immediately sets its own bounds a second time to send the current offset back to zero/zero. The problem may be that if I do both, it gets confused, but if I only invalidate on the first call it gets the wrong information, whereas if I don't invalidate on the first, I don't get the second at all. Chicken/Egg.

Comment: It's going to be hard to diagnose without more detail about your layout, but like you said there's probably lots of code. What's your layout broadly doing?

Comment: I'm 99% certain there's no bugs in the portion that lays out the views. I've analysed the two lists of frames that determine where the cells should be and both the new and the old frames are exactly right. Just so you know though, it acts much like a regular flow layout, arranging cells of unequal size in wrapped rows separated by section, except that the section 'header' views are down the left hand side instead of across the top.

Comment: Like I said, it's basically the same code as the tutorial I linked, but with a different frameForItemAtIndexPath: method.